# mlr3 - benchmarking: status messages are only displayed after full benchmark is completed

Tags: progress-bar, status, mlr3

I would like to monitor the progress of benchmark() in mlr3. Benchmarking several models including hyperparameter tuning on a large data set can take hours or even days. I would like to be able to monitor the progress while benchmark is running, so that I can decide whether or not to abort the benchmark. In addition, if status messages are printed during the process, I can abort the process after some parts are completed and know how long certain steps took.  For example, Naive Bayes might have already completed but the hyperparameter tuning for decisions trees is still running (and has been for hours...). That way I could make appropriate changes for the next benchmark run (e.g., limit the search space for decision trees or go with only Naive Bayes).

The problem is that only the first messages ("running resampling instances") is displayed during/at the beginning of the process. The rest only shows up after the full benchmark is completed. In other words, for hours or even days the only status messages displayed is the first one. If one aborts the process, all information about the progress (duration of individual steps) is lost.

This is a very short example. The relevant part of the code is adopted straight from the [mlr3 book](https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/):

```
    design = benchmark_grid(
               tasks = task,
               learners = c(lrn("classif.featureless"), 
               lrn("classif.xgboost")
               ),
               resamplings = resampling
              )
     bmr = benchmark(design)
```

The status message on the start of the benchmark process is displayed right away
[image]

The other messages - inlcuding those on a status only microseconds after the start of the progress - are only displayed once the full benchmarking process is completed.

[image]

In this case, it only takes a minute. But if the benchmark would take hours or days, it would be helpful to observe the messages on a new status right away rather than having to wait until the full process is completed.

I am aware that benchmark() supports progressr::with_progress(), but a percentage level is not detailed enough for me.

Is there a way to get mlr3::benchmark() to display status messages right away throughout the entire process, not just after the process has finished?

Comment: Are you running in parallel or sequentially?

Comment: I am not using any parallelization in the code.

Comment: Thanks. I think I've recognized this as well in the past, seems like the output is hold back by some encapsulated process. Will have a closer look in the next days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this behaviour is the internal call to `future.apply::future_mapply()`. When using `base::mapply()`, the output is printed directly.
The latter can be enforced by setting `options("mlr3.debug" = TRUE)` as shown below.

I've opened a [pull request](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3/pull/692) to also force this behaviour in `future.apply::future_mapply()`, which is the default if `options("mlr3.debug" = FALSE)`.

Here's a temporary workaround

```r
library("mlr3")
tasks = list(tsk("penguins"), tsk("sonar"))
learners = list(lrn("classif.featureless"), lrn("classif.rpart"))
resamplings = list(rsmp("cv"), rsmp("subsampling"))

grid = benchmark_grid(tasks, learners, resamplings)
print(grid)

# workaround
options("mlr3.debug" = TRUE)

benchmark(grid)
```

Answer (score 2):

We are looking into not delaying stdout via future in https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3/pull/692.

Alternatively, you can configure `progressr` to use the `progress` package for progress bars which then outputs additional information (currently running task, learner, iteration):

```
progressr::handlers(global = TRUE)
progressr::handlers("progress")
```